# String input not executed

Tags: java, while-loop

I have developed a code to get the input details of the students marks and print the average as the output. This operation will be performed until the user gives an "n" as an input for the looping condition.But in my code, the user is unable to give the conditional input and the automatically performs the while loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Student

 {

   String reg;

  int maths,phy,che,cse,avg;

void cal()

{

if(maths<50 | phy<50 | che<50 | cse<50)

{

System.out.println("The grade of the student will not be computed");

}

else

{

avg=((maths+phy+che+cse)/4);

if(avg>=91)

{

System.out.println("S");

}

if(avg>=81 && avg<=90)

{

System.out.println("A");

}



if(avg>=71  && avg<=80)

{

System.out.println("B");

}



if(avg>=61  && avg<=70)

{

System.out.println("C");

}


if(avg>=50 && avg<=60)

{

System.out.println("D");

}



}


}

}







 class Main1    //3rd

{

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

            Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
            String r = "Y", a = "Y";

            while (r.contains(a)) {

                Student s = new Student();
                System.out.println("Enter the marks for maths,physics,chemistry,CSE along with your Reg.no first");
                s.reg = w.nextLine();
                s.maths = w.nextInt();
                s.phy = w.nextInt();
                s.che = w.nextInt();
                s.cse = w.nextInt();
                System.out.println("press 'Y' to continue and 'N' to exit");
                a = w.nextLine();
                s.cal();

            }

        }

    }
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT :

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin>java Main1
>
> Enter the marks for maths,physics,chemistry,CSE along with your Reg.no
>   first
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> press 'Y' to continue and 'N' to exit
>
> S
>
> Enter the marks for maths,physics,chemistry,CSE along with your Reg.no
>   first

Comment: Try r.equals(a) instead of contains. Also add a print once you update a to see what the value of a is.

Comment: Put your student class code please

Comment: As mentioned in the Duplicate `Scanner.nextInt` donot register newline so when you press enter it skips the last nextLine statement try `Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());` for all the integer inputs.

Comment: i did try the r.equals(a) , but it still tends to skip that part of updation of value ' a '

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam  yes you are right...but mine is not an integer input since i use a string as an input

Comment: @RafałSokalski    I have updated the code and included the student class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `w.nextLine();` before `System.out.println("press 'Y' to continue and 'N' to exit");` so the main method should looks like that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
    String r = "Y", a = "Y";

    while (r.contains(a)) {

        Student s = new Student();
        System.out.println("Enter the marks for maths,physics,chemistry,CSE along with your Reg.no first");
        s.reg = w.nextLine();
        s.maths = w.nextInt();
        s.phy = w.nextInt();
        s.che = w.nextInt();
        s.cse = w.nextInt();
        w.nextLine(); //------> Added
        System.out.println("press 'Y' to continue and 'N' to exit");
        a = w.nextLine();
        s.cal();
```

Comment: what was the problem in the code ?

Comment: nextInt does not read next line character only the number you enter that's why w.nextLine ( in line   a = w.nextLine();) did that. More information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo